# How to stop the pacer thread running in libjingle webrtc iOS in an audio call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, webrtc, libjingle

I am implementing a webrtc iOS application. When I am checking the cpu usages during call it went to about 105%. I came to see that a pacer thread starts when the call is started but it does not stops when the call is ended.

Is it a bug in libjingle lib. I am using https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: you have to update the library. The new build of webrtc has this solved.